# Why does the System.Type overload equality operator?

Tags: c#, .net, types, operator-overloading, system.type

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.op_equality?view=net-6.0) don't answer. [Sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs) also:

```
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
    [Pure]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public static extern bool operator ==(Type left, Type right);
```

So, I'm curious why `System.Type` overloads operator `==`? Could there be more than 1 instance of `Type` class representing some particular type? Or what else could be in the overloaded operator definition?

Comment: Maybe the source of Net Core is a bit more telling (UnderlyingType handling) https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Type.cs,582

Comment: @Roman Both return the same Type instance. So the standard implementations (of equals and the == operator using reference comparison) should already work i assume?

Comment: @Ralf, thank you! Looks like there is an answer